# Is it possible to schedule an automated task to run in a specific terminal once an hour?

Tags: linux, shell, scheduled-tasks

I have several script ideas I would very much like to bring into existence, however I have been stuck on this issue for quite sometime and can't seem to get a solid answer.

I want to be able to set a schedule for a script to run inside of a specificed terminal consistently.

For example (For the sake of painting a better image): An usage of this could be having an 80x20 pixel terminal in the bottom right of my screen that uses `"cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's $(date +%A) and the time is $(date +%r)"` to display the current time and date once an hour.

I'm really struggling with almost every aspect of this. Could anyone shed some light as to how I would target a specific terminal and / or how to schedule a script to even execute in a terminal?

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `watch` command!

```
watch -n 3600 "cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's $(date +%A) and the time is $(date +%r)"
```

Comment: Hm.. Watch does look extremely relevant and useful, thank you. However the example left me a bit confused with an error: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: No problem! Another useful command is `at`, for scheduling jobs to run in a terminal at a specific time.